# chrome displays ajax response when refresh button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am Laravel developer and building an app. I am using the following techs

- Laravel 8
- JQuery

I am facing a problem that when I submit a form using jquery ajax request it successfully submits and returns a response but when I refresh the same page after submitting the form instead of refreshing the page it shows the response from the last ajax request on the screen. please note that routes which i am using for get and post requests are the same but i have done that in my previous projects and it was working fine there.I am posting the code below please guide me

- view

```html
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-secondary">{{ __('Consultants') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body bg-light">
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="addbtn">Add Consultant</button>
                            <a href="{{url('consultant')}}">test</a>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="consultantModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg " role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-secondary">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="consultantModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body bg-light">
                <form id="cnsltform">
                    <input type="hidden" id="cnslt_id" name="cnslt_id">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Consultant Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Consultant Name">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback name">

                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="speciality" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Speciality</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="speciality" name="speciality" placeholder="Speciality">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback speciality">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fees" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Fees</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="fees" name="fees" placeholder="Fees">
                            <div class="invalid-feedback fees">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>





            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="savecnslt">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                

            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@endsection

@section('js')
   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });


        $('#cnsltform').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#savecnslt').hide();
            var fd = $(this).serialize();
            // var totdata = totdata + '&items' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(tbldata));
            $.ajax({
                
                dataType: "json",
                data: fd,
                url: "{{ route('consultant.store')}}",
                cache: false,
                // processData: false,
                // contentType: false,
                type: 'POST',
                
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#savecnslt').show();
                    console.log(data);
                    // Swal.fire({
                    //     icon: 'success',
                    //     text: 'categories added successfully',
                    //     onAfterClose: () => {
                    //         window.close();
                    //     }
                    // });
                },
                // error: function(data) {
                //     var subdata = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                //     jQuery.each(subdata.errors, function(key, value) {
                //         $(`#${key}`).addClass('is-invalid');
                //         $(`.invalid-feedback.${key}`).text(value);
                //         $(`.invalid-feedback.${key}`).show();
                        
                //     });

                //     return;
                // }
            })



        });
    });

        $('#addbtn').click( function () {

            $('#consultantModal .modal-title').text('Add Consultant');
            
            $('#consultantModal').modal('show');
            $('#consultantModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#name').trigger('focus');
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

- controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Consultant;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ConsultantController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {   
        return view('consultants');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        info('ok');
        
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'speciality' => 'required',
            'fees' => 'required',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'name.required' => 'Consultant Name must be entered',
            'speciality.required' => 'Consultant Speciality must be entered',
            'fees.required' => 'Consultant Fees must be entered',
            
        ];
       
        Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages)->validate();

        return response()->header('Vary', 'Content-Type' )->json('ok');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Consultant  $consultant
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Consultant $consultant)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Consultant  $consultant
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Consultant $consultant)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Consultant  $consultant
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Consultant $consultant)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Consultant  $consultant
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Consultant $consultant)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

- routes file

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
    return 'All Cache cleared';
});

Auth::routes();
// Auth::routes(['verify' => true, 'register' => false]);

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::resource('/pt-admissions', App\Http\Controllers\PtAdmissionController::class);
    Route::resource('consultant', App\Http\Controllers\ConsultantController::class);

    
});
```

the response is shown like
[image]

Note: Routes of get and post are the same only difference is that one is get and the other is post and by changing get route my problem can be solved but I want to keep routes the same

Comment: Do you clear this line please? _but when i refresh the same page after submitting form instead of refreshing page_

Comment: @Espresso i meant when i submit the form and then refresh my tab then it shows me the response. But thanks for you quick reply my problem is solved.Actually there was a service worker which was causing that issue so i unregistered that in my browsers

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Are you sure that this is related to Laravel or PHP?

Comment: @NicoHaase i don't think it is related to Laravel or PHP because when I ran the project in Microsoft edge there was no problem. Actually few days earlier I was working on PWA apps due to which a service worker generated in browser so when I unregistered that service worker my problem solved

Comment: Then please edit your question to focus on the relevant parts. And if that code was running some days ago, why not check what you've changed in between?